# Coldfusion loop behavior

Tags: coldfusion

I'm not really familiar with Coldfusion, but I'm reading through some code and saw this:

```
 <CFLOOP INDEX="element" LIST="#FIELDNAMES#">
    <CFSET REP_LIMIT = 0>
    <CFSET E_VALUE = EVALUATE(#ELEMENT#)>
```

I have two questions:
1) Is that setting E_VALUE to be the current index? If so, what's with the EVALUATE? and 2) Is this a poor and/or dangerous use of EVALUATE?

Comment: What is the context of the code? This looks like a very bad code but in a certain context it might make more sense. For example is there a "query loop" around this code? In all likely hood the Evaluate(Element) code should be replace by a scoped reference such as form[element], url[element], combination of url/form references, or queryvarname[element][queryvarname.currentrow].

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate is used primarily to evaluate dynamically named variables, such as form variables.  If you don't know what form variables might be submitted from a form, you can simply loop through the fieldname by accessing FORM.fieldnames.

(http://cfprimer.blogspot.com/2005/03/avoid-evaluate.html).  In 14 years of coding CF, I have seen it used only a handful of times. In my opinion, it's bad practice to set yourself up in such a manner as to not know in advance what form elements will be submitted.

In your example, the index is set to "element".  So, while looping, whatever is in your list of "fieldnames" will be an element.

If you wanted to output those fieldnames, you would do something like this:

```
<cfset fieldnames = "firstname,lastname,email">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="element" list="#fieldnames#">
     #element#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

This would output like this:

```
firstname
lastname
email
```

Comment: Just figured a small addition would be worthwhile to your lovely explanation, in that `<CFSET E_VALUE = ELEMENT>` would be identical to the `<CFSET E_VALUE = EVALUATE(#ELEMENT#)>`, or alternatively just use `E_VALUE`.  Just not worth adding a seperate answer just for that :)

Comment: Small typo, I think you meant to type "it is equivalent to FORM[ Element ] :) **Edit** Oops, sorry. I just noticed the previous comment was from Simon not you @Evik.

Comment: One other note about #2. Yes, using `evaluate` in that situation is generally discouraged because it is not necessary. All "post" variables are available in the system structure `FORM`. So fields are easily accessed with associative array notation, like Simon mentioned. ie Using `FORM[ Element ]` rather than `FORM("element")`

Comment: Ack.. that very last line should read "using `FORM[ Element]` rather than `EVALUATE("element")`.

Comment: Another option could be to just `<cfloop collection="#form#" item="element">` though that would then hit all fields submitted so not suitable if wishing to hit specific.  And yes I did forget the form[] part, I apologise for that - too late to edit that comment now!